# How can I connect from my Android application to WebApi?

Tags: android, json, asp.net-web-api, deserialization, okhttp

I have an `WebApi` Application and I serialized my data to PC's `localhost`. 
I want to see that datas on My Android application. And i wrote an application with  `okhttp3` library. But its didnt work, when i replace my url with a real url for example: coindesk's api url its working well. what is interesting is that when i writing my localhost address its dont throwing any error, its just closing application on my phone. Here my codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView mTextViewResult;
private Button ExecuteButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_wiev_result);
    ExecuteButton = findViewById(R.id.btnCallMethod);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String url = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json";
    //String url = "localhost:59085/api/Students";



    ExecuteButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if(response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    final String myResponse = response.body().string();

                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(() -> mTextViewResult.setText(myResponse));
                }

            }
        });
    });
```

**Here my Json Datas:**

[image: Here my Json Datas:]

Comment: Could you show what `localhost:59085/api/Students` endpoint returns?

Comment: Maybe you are connected to your 3G rather than your wireless router so you don't have access to your localhost

Comment: @MichałZiober Post has been updated.

Comment: `JSON` looks like as valid. What is the exception. Could you also show `StackTrace`?

Comment: @AntonMakov it doesn't work also on emulators.

Comment: Have you tried 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost? Are you using xmpp/wamp as your localhost?

Comment: @AntonMakov No im not.I still don't know whats the error.

Comment: @AntonMakov so i tried to putting BreakPoint on side of WebApi but it didnt get a request.

Comment: @AntonMakov I using IIS Express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved my problem by myself. Honestly it is necessary to pass a lot of steps to solve this problem. I will tell step by step.

**Step 1:** Open Windows Defender -> firewall and network protection -> Common Network -> Close protection for this.

**Step:2** : Install Jexus Manager, open it and go to sites tab under your pc name and right click and Add Website. Give a website name and choose your web application path under Physical path. Give a port e.g. 61508. For hostname use 127.0.0.1, for IP Adress use your IPv4 address and click OK button.

**Step 3:** At left side click your sitename and click right on opened area and go to -> Manage Website -> Start. And click Manage Website - > Browse and check your web site is working well.

**Step 4:** Now open android and set your current URL as: `http://10.0.2.2:61508/api/Students` then application will work well.